# Is there any way to automate the process of creating tags and triggers in google tag manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have n number of components and right now I am creating separate tags and triggers for each component. But I want to automate this process. Means if there is way to create a template or format and automatically the tags and triggers get creates in GTM.

Is it possible? Also I am using GA-4 for analysis.

I tried templates in gtm but was not able to automate the process of creating tags and triggers.

Answer (score 0):

GTM has an [API](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2) that allows you to create tags, triggers and control your containers/versions programmatically.

For your use case, however, instead of creating tags and triggers for each component, you could just have one tag and trigger for all of them, or group the components together and have one tag and trigger per group.

This approach is easily and commonly used via the [dataLayer](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/datalayer) implementation.

So, say, you'd have groups of components like: buttons, accordions, modals, dialogues, messages, etc.

Let's take a look at the messages group. It would have four types of messages: success, info, warning and errors. And The push structure would look as follows (message as an example):

```
dataLayer.push({
 'event': 'message',
 'action': '< shown | dismissed >',
 'type': '< success | info | warning | error>',
 'message': '<the text of the message>',
 'location': '< header | body | footer | console>'
});
```

now using this template you're effectively covering all message components with one dataLayer message template and one tag/trigger in GTM. This is a very simple model to manage on both sides: the front-end and GTM.

Simlar with, say, buttons:

```
dataLayer.push({
 'event': 'button click',
 'type': '< general navigation | back | continue | product CTA | advertisement | external link | social media>',
 'message': '<the text of the button>'
});
```

One tag/trigger covering all buttons. GTM will still be perfectly able to inject custom logic and override any field with JS in case front-end sends garbage and there are no resources to fix it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information @BNazaruk. I will try this approach. Also do you have any reference videos or documents related to this?

Comment: Well I linked the documentation in the answer. As for videos, I know people make a few on datalayer implementation, but videos are much slower than the documentation, so I don't know much about them.

Comment: Okay. No issue and thank you.

Comment: I have created one customHTML tag and added the infor. in dataLayer.push(). And the trigger is "all elements click". So when I click on the button I can see the tag and also event. But how can I send the data to GA4 analytics?

I want to send different data according to component types to GA4 for creating reports.

Comment: okay, it seems that my answer assumed a higher level of knowledge than you have. 1. You don't use all elements click trigger with no additional conditions. 2. you don't need custom html if you use it for dataLayer. The DL is meant to be populated by your site's front-end. 3. You have an option to track things without DL, for that you use appropriate tag types rather than CHTML. Here: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9442095?hl=en

Comment: yes I am new to GTM but I know about tags and triggers. My motive is this only to basically automate the process of creating the tags & triggers for each component having different types and send the data to google analytics 4. I have connected gtm with drupal site.

Comment: Right now I am creating multiple GA-4 tags with multiple triggers manually. But I don't want to create it manually every time. I hope I am able to explain the situation.

Comment: You were able to explain it the first time. This answers gives a few ways to achieve that. Ask more questions if something's not clear.